# SQL optimization JOIN before table scan?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query similar to

```
SELECT columnName 
FROM 
     (SELECT columnName, someColumnWithXml 
      FROM _Table1
      INNER JOIN _Activity ON _Activity.oid = _Table1.columnName
      INNER JOIN _ActivityType ON _Activity.activityType = _ActivityType.oid
      --_ActivityType.forType is a string
      WHERE _ActivityType.forType = '_Disclosure'
        AND _Activity.emailRecipients IS NOT NULL) subquery
WHERE subquery.someColumnWithXml LIKE '%'+'9D62EE8855797448A7C689A09D193042'+'%'
```

There are 15 million rows in `_Table1` and the `WHERE subquery.someColumnWithXml LIKE '%'+'9D62EE8855797448A7C689A09D193042'+'%'` results in an execution plan that performs a full table scan on all 15 million rows. The subquery results in only a few hundred thousand rows and those are all the rows that really need to have the `LIKE` run on them. Is there a way to make this more efficient by running the `LIKE` only on the results of the subquery rather than running a TABLE SCAN with a `LIKE` on 15,000,000 rows? The `someColumnWithXML` column is not indexed.

Comment: Why use a subquery at all?  In any case the optimizer rearranges operations, so there is no "before"/"after" the `join`.

Comment: Right, the optimizer is doing a horrible job, so I'm wondering if there are any hints or a way to force it to do the operations in a certain order. Not being a full time SQL guru I don't really know much about how SQL hints work and looking over the documentation so far I haven't found anything useful.

Comment: You are getting a full table scan because of the leading wild card on that `LIKE` operator... there is no way to avoid that (except for not using the leading %). You can drop the sub-query into a temp table or a cte and try that, but it'll still be a full scan, though on a smaller result set..

Comment: You are saying that if you only run subquery you get less than a million, but if you add the filter the predicate get push down to do a full scan on the 15 000 000 rows? I would like to see both plans. Also, see if you can create a computed column that extracts the value you want to filter by from the xml, make it persistent and then you can have a non-clustered index over that.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT columnName, someColumnWithXml
FROM _Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     _Activity a
     ON a.oid = t1.columnName INNER JOIN
     _ActivityType at
     ON a.activityType = at.oid --_ActivityType.forType is a string
WHERE at.forType = '_Disclosure' AND
      a.emailRecipients IS NOT NULL AND
      t1.someColumnWithXml LIKE '%'+'9D62EE8855797448A7C689A09D193042'+'%';
```

You have a challenge with optimizing this query.  I don't know if the filtering conditions are particularly restrictive.  If they are, then indexes on:

- `_ActivityType(forType, oid)`
- `_Activity(activityType, emailRecipients, oid)`
- `_Table1(columnName)`

If these don't help, then you might an index on the XML column.  [Perhaps an XML index would work.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-indexes-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)  Such an index would not really help for a generic `LIKE`, but that might not be needed if you parse the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the in the subquery directly avoinding the scan for unuseful rows

```
      SELECT columnName, someColumnWithXml 
      FROM _Table1
      INNER JOIN _Activity on _Activity.oid = _Table1.columnName
      INNER JOIN _ActivityType on _Activity.activityType = _ActivityType.oid
      --_ActivityType.forType is a string
      WHERE _ActivityType.forType = '_Disclosure'
      AND _Activity.emailRecipients IS NOT NULL
      someColumnWithXml LIKE '%'+'9D62EE8855797448A7C689A09D193042'+'%'
```